# Problema con Android Studio, XML corruptos, layouts corruptos, etc

Tags: android-studio

Buenas noches/dias/Tardes,

Tengo un problema algo grave, estaba trabajando con Android Studio cuando se me reinició el PC, el problema es que a la vuelta, no me funciona nada de lo que tenía hecho, si abro los Xml de Values, aparecen como corruptos, con textos cortados a la mitad o como sif ueran otros archivos distintos a lo que tenía.
Con los layouts, lo mismo, me aparecen como linearlayout, cuando eran constraintlayout, aparte en la vista previa sale un cuadro en gris con el texto "keyboard".

Las Class, ahora cambiaron de icono, aparecen con una "J" (antes aparecían con una C) y muestran infinidad de errores del tipo "Cannot resolve the symbol...", me imagino que todo porque no reconoce ni me aparece nada en los layouts.

He intentado revertir en el History, pero nada, continúo igual.

También he borrado la carpeta .idea y nada, igual.
¿Alguna idea de que puedo hacer?

**Edito:** (Perdón, que publiqué como respuesta nueva en un principio)

Esto es lo que me encuentro cuando accedo a los layouts:

[image: Layout]

No hay errores en el XML, pero si en Class, me he fijado que cambiando el tema si que se ve "mejor", auqnue la ActionBar desapareció.

Antes de que se reiniciara el pc, estaba probando con diferentes layouts para landscape y otros tamaños, creaba y borraba. Lo comento por si alguien sabe si pueden venir por ahí los tiros.

Gracias y perdonad las molestias.

Comment: eso nunca me ha pasado, trabajas con repositorios??? eso te salvaría la vida en caso de no poder revertir lo dañado, prueba hacer un clean project a ver si esto te resuelve el asunto

Comment: gracias pro la contestación, el clean project ya lo he hecho, lo curioso de todo es que si pruebo a ver en el dispositivo virtual, aparece todo OK, pero en android studio aparecen errores por todos lados, hasta errores de codificación, como que no está en UTF8. El proyecto creo que no lo he perdido del todo.

Comment: Ya conseguí solucionarlo, he tenido que borrar varias carpetas para que las creara de nuevo, tanto en la carpeta de la app como en las carpetas de Android Studio. A mayores usé algunos archivos de una copia de seguridad que tenía de unos días antes (sobre todo los archivos de la carpeta values), parece que de momento todo OK. Muchas gracias

Comment: Recuerda usar repositorios para que evites males mayores a futuro. Saludos

Comment: ¿por qué ocurre esto? A mi me pasó lo mismo y no logro resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

una forma de solucionar el problema es:

- Cerrar Android Studio
- Ubicar la carpeta donde se encuentra el proyecto y cambiarle el nombre
- Abrir Android Studio
- Reabrir el proyecto con la nueva ubicación.

Esto suele pasar cuando Android studio se cierra mal o se apaga la computadora mientras Android Studio esta haciendo alguna tarea